# Cannot commit anymore. What changed?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

As of today, I cannot commit to the Cloud Datastore anymore. I did not upload a new version and lookups + runQuerys work just fine. So, what happened?

I use my own wrapper to communicate with the REST API but since the problem is limited to commits I was wondering if the Cloud Datasore is undergoing some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the report, we're investigating the issue now.

Update: We've addressed the issue. Please join the Google Cloud Datastore downtime notify mailing list for future updates.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gcd-downtime-notify/sNXCFJYFNQU

For future reports about production issues, please refer to the [Contact support](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/support) section of our documentation.